# WFS updating a geometries points

Tags: wfs, geometry, update, wfs-t

I'm trying to work out on how I can insert or overwrite points that are stored in a features/ Layer? I've created a String/Text document which is already converted into GML/XML ready to be pushed to a WFS. But not sure how I can do this, have been reading into it, can't understand how it works.

Comment: What have you been reading so far? WFS standard has some examples.

Comment: I've looked at the GeoServer examples pretty well laid out, but don't quite understand how to use it/ how it works just hoping someone could help me understand what is going on.

Comment: The demo request utility of GeoServer administration utility might be worth a try. There are some ready request which you can select from the drop down menu. In short, you construct a request in XML format and send it to WFS server with http POST method.

Comment: Thats one other thing I don't fully understand how I use. Is POST Requests. How do I send/use them? I'm only using GET requests at the moment